# Memory Management Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I don't understand why memory consumption increases and never gets released (the project is using ARC) when performing the following operations in my program (please bear with me, I'm at a basic level with plain C):

Simplified: somewhere in my program (AppDelegate for example) I call a `macro` which basically is a C function with variable parameters which calls other C functions that are returning some NSStrings.

These are defined and implemented in an Objective-C style class and are used together with a singleton object.

Header:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@end

void  func_1(aTypeDef paramType, NSString *input, ...);
void* func_2(NSString *arg1, NSString *arg2, NSString *arg3);

NSString* string_func_1 (void);
NSString* string_func_2 (int anInt);
NSString* string_func_3 (const char *aString);

#define F2_MACRO func_2( \
string_func_1(), \
string_func_2(anINT), \
string_func_3(aSTRING), \
)

#define F1_MACRO(input, ...) func_1(A_TYPE, input, ##__VA_ARGS__, F2_MACRO)
```

Implementation:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

static NSString *STRING_1;
static NSString *STRING_2;
static NSString *STRING_3;

@implementation MyClass

void  func_1(aTypeDef paramType, NSString *input, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, input);

    NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:input arguments:args];

    fputs([output UTF8String], stdout);

    va_end(args);
}

void* func_2(NSString *arg1, NSString *arg2, NSString *arg3) {

    STRING_1 = arg1;
    STRING_2 = arg2;
    STRING_3 = arg3;

    return NULL;
}

NSString* string_func_1 (void) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"aString"];
}

NSString* string_func_2 (int anInt) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",anInt];
}

NSString* string_func_3 (const char *aString) {
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:aString];
}


@end
```

Every time I call the `F1_MACRO()` in another Objective-C class like `AppDelegate` memory usage increases every time the `string_func_1, string_func_2, string_func_3` return.

I'm sure that my logic and implementation are flawed and I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Show the code for `func_1()`.

Comment: Are you using ARC (automatic reference counting)?

Comment: @joerick Yes, I'm using ARC.

Comment: @Olaf those functions are not C? Sure they use Foundation's objects but the syntax isn't C?

Comment: They are C-style functions, sure.  But given that this question is about memory management of Objective-C objects under ARC, the C tag is highly inappropriate.

Comment: `@implementation MyClass`, `output = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:input arguments:args]` is C? Please point me at the corresponding section in the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html). Even _if_ the syntax would be the same (which it is not), the semantics are different. You would not tag VHDL-code with Ada-tag either.

Comment: @Ben Can you show us the code where the F1_MACRO is called?

Answer (score 1):

`func_1()` is creating a non-autoreleased object.

• If you are using *Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)*, not autoreleasing the object is fine, however it can still lead to apparent memory accretion.   Specifically, if you don't have an explicitly `@autoreleasepool{}` or are not running an event loop on the thread that is calling that function, then the autoreleased object will never be released.

• If you aren't using ARC, then that is a straight up leak.    Add `[output release];` at the end of the `func_1()` function.

Comment: I'm using ARC. The same happens within the scope of an `@autoreleasepool`

Comment: The same happens within the scope of an `@autoreleasepool` which has absolutely no effect if I embed my code inside it in `func_1` or `func_2`. However, If I pass the parameters from the `string_func_#` functions directly to `func_1`  and skip the functions between alltogether, I get absolutely no memory increase (of course, using an @autoreleasepool).

Comment: Run it in Instruments with reference count tracking enabled and see what is still holding on to the objects.